# R- COUNTIFS function

Tags: r

For each timestamp I would like to count the number of trains/buses with a coordinate higher than the reference.
See here below the dataset:

```
structure(list(timestamp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), type = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bus", "Reference", "Train"), class = "factor"), 
    X.coordinate = c(470L, -300L, 25L, 456L, 37L, 19L, 798L, 
    -56L, 489L, 412L, 350L, 278L, 970L, -65L, -894L, 780L, 265L, 
    -25L, 365L, 785L, 95L, 85L)), .Names = c("timestamp", "type", 
"X.coordinate"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add 2 columns. One column that gives for each row with "reference" the number of trains with a coordinate higher than the reference. The second column should give the number of buses with a coordinate higher than the reference.

See here below the desired output:

```
 timestamp      type X.coordinate Train_with_higher_X Bus_with_higher_X
1          1     Train          470                  NA                NA
2          1     Train         -300                  NA                NA
3          1     Train           25                  NA                NA
4          1     Train          456                  NA                NA
5          1     Train           37                  NA                NA
6          1       Bus           19                  NA                NA
7          1       Bus          798                  NA                NA
8          1       Bus          -56                  NA                NA
9          1       Bus          489                  NA                NA
10         1       Bus          412                  NA                NA
11         1 Reference          350                   2                 3
12         2     Train          278                  NA                NA
13         2     Train          970                  NA                NA
14         2     Train          -65                  NA                NA
15         2     Train         -894                  NA                NA
16         2     Train          780                  NA                NA
17         2       Bus          265                  NA                NA
18         2       Bus          -25                  NA                NA
19         2       Bus          365                  NA                NA
20         2       Bus          785                  NA                NA
21         2       Bus           95                  NA                NA
22         2 Reference           85                   3                 4
```

I tried to write some code in R to get this in an elegant way, but my programming skills are too limited for the moment. Is there anybody that knows a solution for this problem? Thank you on beforehand!

Comment: It seems like your example numbers in the Train_with_higher_X column don't match what you describe. There are 4 "Train" rows that have coordinates higher than 350 (rows 1, 4, 13, and 16). Did you mean for the reference row to only count the block of trains and buses above it, but below the previous reference row?

Comment: @user164385 i presume he means _within `timestamp`_

Comment: Indeed I would like to count the number of times within timestamp

Answer (score 1):

This gets the point across (using `data.table`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[ , Train_with_higher_X :=
      sum(X.coordinate[type == "Train"] > 
            X.coordinate[type == "Reference"]), by = timestamp]
```

And similarly for `Bus_with_higher_X`.

It's a bit more complicated to leave the value as `NA` for rows where `type` is not `"Reference"`, but if you're committed to that, fix it up ex-post:

```
DF[type != "Reference", Train_with_higher_X := NA]
```

This approach also relies on there only being *one* row with `type` `"Reference"` within each value of `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to mixing summary data and raw data in a single data frame (and hence having lots of missing values in the summary columns), how about these options:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Count number of buses and trains greater than reference, by timestamp:

```
dat %>% group_by(timestamp) %>%
  mutate(Reference = X.coordinate[type=="Reference"]) %>%
  filter(type != "Reference") %>%
  group_by(timestamp, type) %>%
  summarise(Reference = unique(Reference), 
            numGTref = sum(X.coordinate > Reference))

  timestamp   type Reference numGTref
1         1    Bus       350        3
2         1  Train       350        2
3         2    Bus        85        4
4         2  Train        85        3
```

Mark buses and trains that are greater than reference, by timestamp:

```
dat %>% group_by(timestamp) %>%
  mutate(Reference = X.coordinate[type=="Reference"]) %>%
  filter(type != "Reference") %>%
  group_by(timestamp, type) %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(X.coordinate > Reference, 
                         paste("Greater than", Reference), 
                         paste("Less than", Reference))) %>%
  select(-Reference)

   timestamp   type X.coordinate           Status
1          1  Train          470 Greater than 350
2          1  Train         -300    Less than 350
3          1  Train           25    Less than 350
4          1  Train          456 Greater than 350
5          1  Train           37    Less than 350
6          1    Bus           19    Less than 350
7          1    Bus          798 Greater than 350
8          1    Bus          -56    Less than 350
9          1    Bus          489 Greater than 350
10         1    Bus          412 Greater than 350
11         2  Train          278  Greater than 85
12         2  Train          970  Greater than 85
13         2  Train          -65     Less than 85
14         2  Train         -894     Less than 85
15         2  Train          780  Greater than 85
16         2    Bus          265  Greater than 85
17         2    Bus          -25     Less than 85
18         2    Bus          365  Greater than 85
19         2    Bus          785  Greater than 85
20         2    Bus           95  Greater than 85
```

Comment: this is the better answer from a programming/data management practices point of view, as much as I hate `dplyr` syntax :p

Comment: @MichaelChirico Wow, I don't think my R syntax has ever made anyone gag before :) (well, at least no one else has told me about it).

Answer (score 1):

Getting familiar with packages like `data.table` and `dplyr`, like other answers suggest, is definitely a valuable investment of your time. But if you want to solve this problem using more familiar tools, that's also possible. You can do this without any extra packages by combining some base R functions: `mapply`, `ifelse`, and `with`, into the following lines of code (where I've named your data frame `d`)

```
bus_sum <- function(x, y) with(d[d$timestamp == x & d$type == "Bus",], sum(X.coordinate > y))
d$Bus_with_higher_X <- ifelse(d$type == "Reference", mapply(FUN = bus_sum, d$timestamp, d$X.coordinate), NA)

train_sum <- function(x, y) with(d[d$timestamp == x & d$type == "Train",], sum(X.coordinate > y))
d$Train_with_higher_X <- ifelse(d$type == "Reference", mapply(FUN = bus_sum, d$timestamp, d$X.coordinate), NA)
```

The result is pretty much exactly what you wanted, I believe.

```
   timestamp      type X.coordinate Train_with_higher_X Bus_with_higher_X
1          1     Train          470                  NA                NA
2          1     Train         -300                  NA                NA
3          1     Train           25                  NA                NA
4          1     Train          456                  NA                NA
5          1     Train           37                  NA                NA
6          1       Bus           19                  NA                NA
7          1       Bus          798                  NA                NA
8          1       Bus          -56                  NA                NA
9          1       Bus          489                  NA                NA
10         1       Bus          412                  NA                NA
11         1 Reference          350                   2                 3
12         2     Train          278                  NA                NA
13         2     Train          970                  NA                NA
14         2     Train          -65                  NA                NA
15         2     Train         -894                  NA                NA
16         2     Train          780                  NA                NA
17         2       Bus          265                  NA                NA
18         2       Bus          -25                  NA                NA
19         2       Bus          365                  NA                NA
20         2       Bus          785                  NA                NA
21         2       Bus           95                  NA                NA
22         2 Reference           85                   3                 4
```

The functions `bus_sum` and `train_sum` take a timestamp and a reference coordinate, and count the number of rows of each type that have an `X.coordinate` greater than the reference coordinate (using `with` restricts consideration to only the part of the data frame that matches that timestamp and type). These two functions differ only in `d$type == "Bus"` vs `d$type == "Train"`, so it would be quite easy to generalize this with another argument to the function. Putting each function inside `mapply` calls it for the timestamp and type of each row. Then wrapping that `mapply` inside an `ifelse` just manually sets all non-reference rows to `NA`.